# C#/.net Unable to use bitmap with "using System.Drawing" and reference to System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am trying to use Bitmap/Image from System.Drawing and I have both:

```
using System.Drawing
```

and a reference to the Assembly System.Drawing within my project. But I still get the error:

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this .NET Core?

Comment: it is .NET Core

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not available in .NET Core, you can explore the API's in the [API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netcore-2.0)

Comment: RIP. I'm trying to process an image to turn it into a barcode number. Would you have any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: There is a library called [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) that is solving a lot of these issues in .NET Core.  Install it via nuget

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know how it goes